# Why my markdown syntax is not working?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

I'd like to edit text with markdown syntax. Searching for ways of using mixed syntax in the same file I've discovered [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18553/is-it-possible-to-make-a-specific-section-have-a-different-syntax) with an answer saying that if I add the line `let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['c']` on my vimrc file it'd accept the `c` language syntax. Alternativey, there's also [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/mixed-color-syntax-in-vim) with an answer that recommends installing the [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) and [vim-pandoc-syntax](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax) plugins.

In my case, none of those solutions are working... I've tried adding the line `let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['c']` on my vimrc file and opening a markdown file with a small piece of `c` code and the syntax was not working. Also, I use `VimPlug` for installing plugins, so I removed all other plugins that I had installed and added the following on my vimrc file:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc'
Plug 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax'
call plug#end()
```

Together with installing them with `:PlugInstall` on a file. But that didn't work for me at all as well. Am I missing something? In my view the markdown syntax would be working as soon as I had the vim-pandoc and vim-pandoc-syntax installed... Just like it's with other plugins related to syntax on Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that in order to make those solutions work I need to name the file as `.markdown` or, alternatively, activate it with `:set ft=markdown` (`:argdo set ft=markdown` for doing it on all files in buffer). In my case, the solution of adding the line `let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['html', 'python', 'bash=sh', 'c', 'javascript']` with all languages that I need worked better. The `vim-pandoc` plugin doesn't seem to highlight syntaxes correctly (I've tested the bash and c syntax).

Comment: `.md` should also work as an extension as well. If you *only* need the syntax, you can `:setlocal syntax=markdown`, but typically you *want* the filetype.

Comment: That's an alternative... Actually I'm working with markdown files from TiddlyWiki. So, all the files end with `.tid`... In this specific case, adding the line `autocmd BufEnter *.tid :setlocal filetype=markdown` in my vimrc file completely solved the problem because it'll automatically see all my `.tid` files as `.markdown` files.

Comment: Using `BufRead` is slightly better than `BufEnter` (because `BufRead` will only fire once, when the buffer is first opened, while `BufEnter` every time you enter that buffer), but yeah associating the extension with the type is the way to go.